# Windows Editor that is suitable for both code and doc

Tags: windows, text-editor, source-code

Need to write some note about some program, such note contains source code copied from the source code of that program which need to prevent line wrap. The note also contains comments (not comments in the source code with need to prevent line wrap too) about the source code which need a text editor that can do line wrap like Office Word.

This is like Office Word plus "pasted without line wrap" which create a paragraph that have very long page width.

The note is mainly a note which can be formated like set font size/colors. It is not a source code with comments!

The platform is Windows 10.

Comment: Normally, the way people handle this is to use their code editor and write the note in Markdown or HTML or some other markup language. Alternatively, you can paste just the code into Word, and use formatting to differentiate the code from the prose. Whether you use a code editor or a word processor, you most likely won't be able to have some parts (automatically) wrap and some not. If the code you don't want to wrap is wider than the note you want to write, you can set different paragraph "margins" in Word.

Comment: @JohnY That's too much pain, automation is needed. Now using super large word document with manual line break, even so many code get wrapped. Why not code editor? Need table of contents and fonts/colors for notes.

Comment: If you are using Word, then I would definitely NOT use manual line breaks except within the code sections. I don't think you are going to find exactly what you are looking for. Most people either stick to Word and deal with pasting code in, or they learn a full-fledged documentation system, which is always going to be based on some kind of markup language. Those who put a premium on having control generally prefer the latter. Also, it is easier to write scripts to help you with markup than to write scripts to help you with Word. Good luck!

Comment: @JohnY I'll try manual paste of code to word.

Comment: @JohnY In Word you can't set a paragraph to be wider than the page width...Doesn any office like text editor support this?

Comment: Of course you can't set anything to be wider than page width. That wouldn't make any sense. You can set the page width to be however wide you need to hold the code, then set all the OTHER paragraphs to be narrower. However, you should be aware that virtually no one does this. The normal thing to do is to make the source code fit, using the rules of the programming language. It's an unnatural reading experience if the source code and the prose are vastly different widths.

Comment: @JohnY The best way should be X-scrollable code box in Word which may be implemented by OLE to embed a notepad thing into the document.

Comment: @JohnY Like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20120016/how-to-show-code-snippets-in-ms-word-document-as-it-shows-in-stackoverflow-scro?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you jump on the developer side of that problem and edit your prose using [Asciidoc](https://asciidoctor.org/) format. There are quite correct editors (as an example [AsciidocFX](https://asciidocfx.com/)). This is quite a simple format (more or less like Markdown), but it will allow you to include code with ease, and apply really good text formatting.